# Is there a way of using StartupEventArgs in app.xaml.cs in a Prism WPF Application?

Tags: wpf, prism

I would like use StartupEventArgs to determine which application settings JSON file is used in a C# WPF prism application.  Is this possible?

I have overridden the OnStartup method in App.xaml.cs to run use the StartupEventArgs, but as expected from the Prism documentation this causes the main window to open twice.  I cannot find anything in the Prism documentation advising how do this, any help would be greatly appreciated!

*Edit* The on startup method I am using that causes two windows to open

```
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        string env = null;
        // Check for env in startup args
        for (int i = 0; i < e.Args.Length; i++)
        {
            if (e.Args[i].Equals("-config"))
            {
                _environmentTag = e.Args[i + 1];
                switch (e.Args[i + 1])
                {
                    case "Live":
                        env = "appsettings.json";
                        break;
                    case "Test":
                        env = "appsettings.Development.json";
                        break;
                    default:
                        env = null;
                        break;
                }
            }
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Environment.CurrentDirectory)
                .AddJsonFile(env, optional: false, reloadOnChange: false);
            _configuration = builder.Build();

            OnInitialized();
            base.OnStartup(e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What, _exactly_, are you referring to be "application settings JSON file"? (Because WPF on .NET Framework defaults to using `app.config`, with JSON only really used in .NET 5 and later, which comes with MEDI in which case you should be using `IHost` to do stuff like this). Please provide more details.

Comment: I suggest you use a pre build action to copy the appropriate dev / Test / live versions of an appsettings.JSON  file with a consistent name. Then you don't need to check command line variables when running your app.

Comment: Overriding `OnStartup` should not make your Main Window open twice.  Where in the Prism documentation does it say that?   It certainly does not do that to my MainWindow.  Could you share your OnStartup?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't call `OnInitialized`, because `base.OnStartup` already does that (with actually initializing first).

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    string env = null;
    // Check for env in startup args
    for (int i = 0; i < e.Args.Length; i++)
    {
        if (e.Args[i].Equals("-config"))
        {
            _environmentTag = e.Args[i + 1];
            switch (e.Args[i + 1])
            {
                case "Live":
                    env = "appsettings.json";
                    break;
                case "Test":
                    env = "appsettings.Development.json";
                    break;
                default:
                    env = null;
                    break;
            }
        }
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Environment.CurrentDirectory)
            .AddJsonFile(env, optional: false, reloadOnChange: false);
        _configuration = builder.Build();

        base.OnStartup(e); // this will initialize everything and then call OnInitialized
    }
}
```

Depending on what you need `_configuration` for, it might be a good idea to move the code to `CreateContainerExtension` or `RegisterTypes` (reminder: you can get the command line args anywhere by calling `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()`).

Comment: I removed `OnInitialized()` but the software was still opening two Windows, so as you advised I have moved the _configuration initialisation to `RegisterTypes` and its now working.  `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()` was the knowledge I was missing.  Thanks very much for the help!